# rules in cricket for overseas players

Tags: rules, cricket

I'm from india im coming to other countries. Am I allowed to play and represent immediately or I should wait until 4 years. I have not played any level cricket here knowing its political

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the level of cricket you want to play, and on the regulations of the individual organising committees who administer the level you wish to play at.

In general, there's usually no issue in playing at a social level, and as you rise through the ranks more restrictions are in place. To play international cricket for another country in general requires four years of residency in that country, but there are many twists & turns to the regulations. I'd suggest you go through the various documents [on the ICC site](http://www.icc-cricket.com/cricket-rules-and-regulations).

Comment: Ian morgan an irish not residential of England for four years I think rules are different for different status like test playing and associated

Comment: You mean Eoin Morgan? He served a four-year residency in the UK, while playing for Middlesex. The rules are different if you're transferring between a test nation and an associate, but only around how long you can play for the associate while serving that residency. The more important question, though is this: is this relevant to you? Are you capable of playing at that level, to require the residency? If you're a social player it's irrelevant.